How to make Eloquent more performant in Laravel
I have this table:
+-----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                        | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| exact_location_unknown      | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| lat                         | decimal(10,8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lng                         | decimal(11,8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| streetname                  | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| house_number                | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| house_number_addition       | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| postalcode                  | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_id                     | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| municipality_id             | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| internal_notes              | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at                  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at                  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

With indexes set to:

id
city_id
municipality_id
name
streetname
house_number
house_number_addition

Current count of records is nearly 200.000. I need to list duplicates based on name and/or streetname and house_number and/or house_number_addition. I'm using Laravel v10.26.2 and this is in my controller (simplified):
$query = Company::query();

if ($request->has('filter') && !empty($request->filter) && is_array($request->filter)) {
    foreach ($request->filter as $filter => $value) {
        ...
        if ($filter === 'show_duplicate_company_names' && !empty($value)) {
            $query->whereIn('name', function ($sub) {
                $sub->select('name')
                    ->from('companies')
                    ->groupBy('name')
                    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
            });
        }
    }
}

$query = $query->paginate($pageLength, ['*'], 'page', $request->page);

return new Collection($query);

As curiosity, I also ran this SQL code directly:
select *
from `companies`
where `name` in (
    select `name`
    from `companies`
    group by `name`
    having COUNT(`name`) > 1
)

Which should return all duplicates. But the performance is ... poor. I honestly left running the SQL code for about an hour and still didn't get back any results. How can I write the SQL query to be performant in my case? Waiting few seconds is an option (will simply add a note in my webapp that selecting this filter will take time), but waiting a minute or more is not an option.
EDIT:
After I realized there's Lary, A Laravel's AI, I asked it to provide the solution, if possible. It came up with this and it works nicely:
$query->join(
    DB::raw('(SELECT `name` FROM `companies` GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as `duplicate_names`'),
    'companies.name',
    '=',
    'duplicate_names.name'
);

EDIT 2: as per request, adding a raw SQL queries Eloquent produces:
with JOIN:
select *
from `companies`
inner join (
    SELECT `name`
    FROM `companies`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING COUNT(`name`) > 1) as `duplicate_names` on `companies`.`name` = `duplicate_names`.`name`

with WHERE IN:
select *
from `companies`
where `name` in (
    select `name`
    from `companies`
    group by `name` having COUNT(`name`) > 1

And yes, the difference between HAVING(*) and HAVING('name') was added by me, since I want to do as minimal select as possible. Do note that I also tried this one before, not sure why I added the code with HAVING(*).

What does the database return when you run that same query with EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE before it?

Similarly, execution time and explain output for the group by subquery. Please update your question with the full create statement for the table (SHOW CREATE TABLE companies), instead of the output of DESCRIBE. And some index stats (SHOW INDEXES FROM companies). You will probably find a join will be much faster than using IN - select * from `companies` join ( select `name` from `companies` group by `name` having COUNT(`name`) > 1 ) t on companies.name = t.name;

@user1191247 why would a JOIN be faster than a WHERE? Also, couldnt you add an ORDER BY name to the subquery so MySQL can infer its ordered, and therefore efficiently use it?

@Flame Apparently it is. I remembered on Lary and asked him, he provided examples with JOIN and those worked nicely. Will add them into my question.

I cant fathom that it should make a difference; according to the DB engine it should be the same operation. I'd like to see an example where the same query would be faster with a JOIN than with a WHERE

Can you include the exact raw query output of both queries? I'd like to tinker with them a bit and see whats causing the difference.

@Flame I think MySQL will do a full table scan when you use WHERE name IN (SELECT ...) but will use the expected index when using JOIN. I have just tested with a similarly structured table and that was the case.

@user1191247 weird because all sources on the internet says that it shouldnt make a difference @KristjanO. there's a difference in your new query, namely HAVING COUNT(*) vs HAVING COUNT(name).

@danblack that is not the Eloquent Laravel uses, stop spamming this.

@Flame Have added SQL outputs. Do note that with JOIN, the code is much faster. Now it outputs results in less than 3 seconds, before it didn't in one hour.

IN ( SELECT ... ) is often poorly optimized; avoid it.
COUNT(name) checks name for being not-null; this is probably irrelevant.
I suggest writing your query this way:
select  c.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  `name`
            FROM  `companies`
            GROUP BY  `name`
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 
         ) AS dups
    JOIN  companies AS c AS `dups` USING(name) 

and be sure to have INDEX(name)
But...  That will provide every row for each dup name.  If you want only one row per dup name, please explain which one you would like.
